# AS3 - Tile image/movieclip along a line

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, line, tile

If possible I would like to tile an image or `MovieClip` along a line using the standard `moveTo()` and `lineTo()` methods, The lines are directional so need to show something similar to `>>>>>>>>>>>>>`. The lines can be at any angle, so using `drawRect()` with `beginBitmapFill()` isn't an option. Also if possible I would like to have the lines animated.

Is this possible or will it require a custom class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible. I am assuming that by lines you mean rectangles (of certain width and are placed at certain angle let say theta.) So one way is, don't use drawRect, instead of this use moveTo and lineTo to make angled rectangles.

```
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.rotate(theta);
graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmapData, matrix);
graphics.moveTo(x0, y0);
graphics.lineTo(x0 + w * Math.cos(theta), y0 + w * Math.sin(theta));
graphics.lineTo(x0 + w * Math.cos(theta) - h * Math.sin(theta), y0 + w * Math.sin(theta) + h * Math.cos(theta));
graphics.lineTo(x0 - h * Math.sin(theta), y0 + h * Math.cos(theta));
graphics.endFill();
```

You can add as many rectangles as you want.